# why am i asked for a cdrom to perform upgrades?

Tags: upgrade, 14.10

I recently downloaded an iso image for ubuntu to install on a friend's laptop and now my installation is asking me to insert a cdrom in order to perform an upgrade. How can I get rid of this and get upgrades only online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *System Settings* > *Software Updates* and uncheck the CD-ROM checkbox at the bottom of the leftmost tab.

This will remove your installation media from the repository list.

You could also do this by manually editing (with root privileges!) the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replacing every `cdrom` at the beginning of a line with `#cdrom` (the `#` marks the line as comment and lets apt-get ignore it).